# Opening too big geojson file on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, geojson

I am using open [dataset](https://github.com/pararawendy/border-desa-indonesia-geojson), basically I download data, unzip it (about 250 MB after unzip) and using code below.

The data consist of 83322 villages across Indonesia, basically I'm OK to open the data partially, for example first 5000, etc.

```
import ast
with open('indonesia_villages_border.geojson') as myfile:
    data = ast.literal_eval(myfile.read())
```

The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. It's probably because the data is too big.

Is there's any ways to open, I'm fine with querying etc.

Comment: I haven't read the file, but it seems has 83322 lines

Comment: maybe `ast.literal_eval` cost the problem.  you can read it with `open`, then use `json.loads` to parse the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('indonesia_villages_border.geojson') as fo:
    data_str = fo.read()
data = json.loads(data_str) 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```